# How do I enable the "print PDF" link on only a specific page?

Tags: 7

I have enabled the [print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module and configured the basic page content type to show a PDF print link under the basic page settings.

[image: basic page content type print setting]

On the [print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module's Links settings page at `admin/config/user-interface/print/ui`, under the  *Advanced Link Options* heading, I can specify the paths where I want to show a PDF print link.

[image: print module link setting]

But it is still showing a "print PDF" link on all basic pages.

I also tried by disabling the print setting under basic page settings, and only entering the path under print links settings, but then it disable the pdf print link from *all* basic pages -- even from the one I want it to show up on.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Link options section at `admin/config/user-interface/print/ui`, making sure you don't have '`content corner`' selected.

Comment: disabling "content corner" doesn't work. I tried with basic page settings have pdf print "show link" enabled and disabling that "content corner"

Comment: I think enabling print link on a specific page of specific content type functionality is not available in print module. Description says: "Show link in system (non-content) pages" and  "Any page that is not a Drupal node. Usually pages generated by Drupal or a module such as Views or Panels."

Comment: The [Printer-friendly pages UI](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/print/plain/print_ui/print_ui.module) module is one of the modules part of the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) project.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install 7.x-1.3 of the [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module instead of 7.x-2.x. In 7.x-1.3 there will be a Link Visibility section in the PDF configuration section that will let you select the pages to display the PDF link on. For some reason this no longer appears in 7.x-2.x, at least I haven't been able to find it.